# How to prevent history syncing across any chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, sync

I want to disable syncing of browser history for my google account. I want to do this because it seems like the best / safest option given that:

1. I like the other syncing features and want to use them at work
2. I don't want all my / my family's browsing activity to upload to my work PC
3. I don't want to faff about with multiple accounts
4. I don't want to have to remember to manually opt out of syncing every time I install a browser at work.

I have just read this question;

[Does Google Chrome sync history between computers?](https://superuser.com/questions/198710/does-google-chrome-sync-history-between-computers)

I have also read several google forum and blog posts on this topic which were less than helpful. [This page](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7028918?p=my_activity&rd=1) seems to suggest I have to disable this feature on all my devices / browsers.

To be clear, I don't want to have to manually disable it for every browser, and I don't want to have to remember to disable it next time I install chrome on some other machine.

Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Navigate to your Google Dashboard. Make sure you are signed in to your Google Account. Now click Reset sync to stop syncing and clear all of your synced data. Afterwards click OK.

This will stop syncing on all your devices. As long as you do not sign in with your Google Account on a new machine, devices will not be synced automatically.

Comment: "I like the other syncing features and want to use them at work" - your answer doesn't address this. It stops all syncing not just history.